# What sanctions is the UK parliament considering against social media executives?

Tags: united-kingdom, technology, social-media, prison, fines

According to a recent [article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/may/05/uk-watchdog-will-have-power-to-impose-huge-fines-on-big-tech-firms) by the Guardian, a new digital watchdog will be set up with the power to impose fines upto 10% of global revenue. In the case of Facebook, this will be upto £10 billion.

Does the proposed legislation mention sanctions - such as prison sentences - against social media executives?

Comment: While it is, of course, Parliament that legislates, it is the Government that drafts the legislation, controls the Commons, and ultimately implements the law. Hence I'd suggest replacing "parliament" with "government" in the title.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: It's parliament that is sovereign in British law. Hence I prefer my own wording.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[According](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/nadine-dorries-bill-mark-zuckerberg-government-children-b2008410.html%3famp) to *The Independent*, that the long awaited Online Safety Bill had been strengthened with:

> the addition of new *criminal offences* such as revenge porn, hate crime, fraud, the sale of illegal illegal drugs or weapons, the promotion or facilitation of suicide, people smuggling and sexual exploitation.

Also three new criminal offences recommended by the Law Commission, have also been added to the bill:

> The new offences cover communications that are sent to convey a threat of serious harm; those sent to cause harm without reasonable excuse; and those sent which are known to be false with the intention of causing non-trivial emotional, psychological or physical harm.

They also say that Nadine Dorries, the Culture Secretary, has said in an interview with *Times Radio* that:

> Under the new rules, senior executives of online platforms could end up in prison, if they do not act ...

> Asked again if senior executives could find themselves in prison if they did not comply, she said, "absolutely."

However, this is disputed by the NSPCC. Their head of child safety has said:

> despite the rhetoric, the governments current proposals mean tech bosses wouldn't be held personally liable for the harmful effects of their algorithms or failing to prevent grooming, and could only be prosecuted for failing to supply information to the regulator.

The maximum prison sentence if they fail to comply is two years. According to *iNews*, the draft bill was to originally

> delay bringing in the power to make named individuals criminally liable for two years after the bill came into law to allow the sector to adjust.

> But Culture Secretary Nadine Dorries ordered the deferral period to be cut down to two months to "strengthen penalties for wrongdoing from the outset."

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at this time, but "civil penalties" for technology executives are contemplated, albeit for the narrow case of impeding investigations. [Quoth the BBC](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.bbc.com/news/technology-61342576.amp):

> "Senior managers will face civil penalties if their firms fail to
> engage properly with requests for information," the government said.
>
> However, it is unclear when exactly the changes will come into force,
> as the government has said the necessary legislation will be
> introduced "in due course".

Those [civil penalties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_penalty?wprov=sfla1) would presumably not include prison.

However, [as noted by the questioner in the comments](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72986/what-sanctions-is-the-uk-parliament-considering-against-social-media-executives/72988#comment302011_72988) and [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/72989/14853), the revised draft version of the Online Safety Bill does contemplate criminal penalties for failure to cooperate with an investigation, if such failure involves intentional or reckless misrepresentation. Concretely:

> Offence in relation to CSEA reporting
>
> (1) A person commits an offence
> if, in purported compliance with a requirement under section 59— (a)
> the person provides information that is false in a material respect,
> and (b) at the time the person provides it, the person knows that it
> is false in a material respect or is reckless as to whether it is
> false in a material respect.
>
> (2) A person who commits an offence under
> this section is liable— (a) on summary conviction in England and
> Wales, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding the maximum summary
> term for either-way offences or a fine (or both); (b) on summary
> conviction in Scotland, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding 12
> months or a fine not exceeding the statutory maximum (or both); (c) on
> summary conviction in Northern Ireland, to imprisonment for a term not
> exceeding 6 months or a fine not exceeding the statutory maximum (or
> both); (d) on conviction on indictment, to imprisonment for a term not
> exceeding two years or a fine (or both).

This also appears to apply to obstructing investigations under the law or failing to comply with  people acting to enforce the law:

> A person commits an offence if— (a) the person intentionally obstructs a person acting under this Schedule; (b) the person fails, without reasonable excuse, to comply with any requirement imposed by a person acting under this Schedule; (c) in response to a requirement imposed by a person acting under this Schedule, the person provides information that is false in a material respect, knowing that it is false in a material respect or being reckless as to whether it is false in a material respect.

Comment: -1: The proposed legislation does mention *criminal offences* and also *prison sentences*. See my answer.

Comment: From your answer, it sounds like they could only end up in prison if they impeded the investigation and failed to pay the civil fines, though. Which is the case with failure to pay civil fines in general, no?

Comment: When you mention the criminal offenses, it's pretty clear those apply to users from the later portion of your answer.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - I have linked to your comment and edited my answer to address the portion of the draft that provides for criminal liability under certain circumstances.

Comment: I asked specifically whether "the proposed legislation mentioned sanctions - such as prison - against social media executives". They do. You didn't.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Thus why I edited my answer to mention those portions of the law. You were right, I was wrong.

Comment: Plaigarising my answer doesn't make your answer correct.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - I gave you credit for the idea and found supporting resources that were not in your answer, namely the text of the law.  You *have* been in academia, right? [This resource](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/student-records-and-data/for-current-students/undergraduate-and-taught-postgraduate/exams-assessments-and-regulations/plagiarism-academic-integrity--exam-offences/) could be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136095/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-mozibur-ullah).